# How do i give a user specific options in disnake slash commands

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I wish to allow users to manage the roles of another user with two operators, add or remove, i also want this to occur in a slash command but i cant get the two options to appear as such attached image. im using the disnake fork of discord.py

[image]

heres my current command setup

```py
@bot.slash_command(description="manages a users roles")
async def manageroles(inter, user:disnake.Member, operation:str):
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```py
async def manageroles(inter, user:disnake.Member, operation:str=commands.Param(choices=["add", "remove"]))
```

Comment: This answer would benefit from the addition of some extra information explaining what the code does. Code block only answers are discouragaed because they provide no value for future readers.